# How to publish iis application to azure virtual machine from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, iis, publish, azure-virtual-machine

I have an azure virtual machine with windows server 2012 r2 operating system. I have a website in this virtual machine. For example, the site's domain name is: www.example.com 
I can publish my site from Visual Studio on my computer to this virtual machine without any problems. But I have a problem.

I am running an application in iis under the example.com/demo virtual path. But I couldn't find how to publish 'demo' web application from visual studio to this path. It wants the name of the website from me, but I want to publish this to iis not as a website, but as an application that runs on www.example.com/demo. How can I do that?

Comment: Did You tried working example from internet ???

Comment: works on the internet. When I put the index.html file in the folder with the demo application, this html file appears on the internet at www.example.com/demo. My problem is to publish this application from visual studio to remote server.

Comment: Did U get adress of azure virtual machine ???

Comment: Of course. Look, I can publish my main site seamlessly from visual studio to the azure virtual machine. I think I couldn't explain my question fully. I have added an application to my website. [Like here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/)
This is the path of the application: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\demo
How can I publish my application to this path from visual studio?

Comment: Accrding to your description, I still couldn't understand your demo application clearly. Do you mean the demo is just a virtual path of the application not the nested application? If the demo is the nested application in your IIS, then you could directly use the deploy to achieve your reuqirement.

Comment: Do you follow the steps in [Publish an ASP.NET Web App to an Azure VM from Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/publish-web-app-from-visual-studio).